# Vertical Lines not appearing in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am trying to make the following table with the table and tabularx packages, but the vertical lines of the last three columns are not appearing.
Can you, please, point me in the right direction?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array, hhline}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \small
    \makebox[3 \textwidth][l]{       %centering table
    \resizebox{0.8 \textwidth}{!}{   %resize table

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c|} 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c||}{\textbf{a}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c||}{\textbf{b}} 
    & 
    \multicolumn{4}{|c||}{\textbf{c}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{
    \textbf{d}} \\
    \hline
    aaaaaaa & bbbbbbb & ccccccc & ddddddd & aaaaaaa & bbbbbbb & ccccccc & ddddddd & aaaaaaa & bbbbbbb & ccccccc & ddddddd & aaaaaaa & bbbbbbb & ccccccc & ddddddd\\ 
    \hline\hline
    0.495 & 0.509 & 0.581 & 0.500 & 0.445 & 0.545 & 0.449 & 0.679 & 0.536 & 0.
    600 & 0.392 & 0.736 & 0.509 & 0.454 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 
    \hline
    0.645 & 0.633 & 0.616 & 0.500 & 0.462 & 0.861 & 0.650 & 0.519 & 0.600 & 0.
    570 & 0.592 & 0.536 & 0.675 & 0.693 & 0.552 & 0.500\\ 
    \hline
    0.549 & 0.489 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.572 & 0.510 & 0.457 & 0.467 & 0.578 & 0.447 
    & 0.496 & 0.316 & 0.535 & 0.510 & 0.433 & 0.426\\ 
    \hline
    0.515 & 0.520 & 0.469 & 0.500 & 0.532 & 0.497 & 0.538 & 0.745 & 0.626 & 0.588
    & 0.569 & 0.591 & 0.615 & 0.623 & 0.536 & 0.452\\ 
    \hline
    0.760 & 0.471 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.749 & 0.542 & 0.574 & 0.379 & 0.673 & 0.563 
    & 0.544 & 0.483 & 0.613 & 0.425 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 
    \hline
    0.604 & 0.527 & 0.430 & 0.500 & 0.469 & 0.498 & 0.547 & 0.400 & 0.537 & 0.434
    & 0.522 & 0.397 & 0.518 & 0.436 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 
    \hline
    0.524 & 0.479 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.715 & 0.528 & 0.658 & 0.585 & 0.697 & 0.523 
    & 0.604 & 0.681 & 0.522 & 0.559 & 0.507 & 0.486\\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    }   %centering table
    }   %resize table

    \caption{Caption}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Thanks

Comment: (i) in `tabularx` at least one column should be of type `X`. (ii) your table is to huge that can be fit in text width. (iii) horizontal lines are draw only to right text border. is possible to make column headers narrowed?

Comment: Also you shouldn't use `\resizebox` as it leads to inconsistent font sizes. And I suppose you mean *Horizontal* lines in your title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, it's simply incorrect to use a `tabularx` environment without employing at least one column of type `X`. A separate issue: Since your table has 16 [!] columns, you should give serious thought to displaying the material in landscape format.

The first table in the following screenshot implements fixes to these two concerns.

In addition, you should also be concerned with making the table more readable. Specifically, all these vertical and horizontal lines do nothing to enhance the material's legibility. In fact, one could argue that they reduce legibility. The second table in the following screenshot (hopefully) demonstrates that by using no vertical lines at all and by using fewer, but well-spaced horizontal lines, the table gets a much more "open" look which encourages readers to actually spend some time perusing the tabular material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default value: 6pt

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| *{3}{*{4}{C|}|} *{4}{C|} } 
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c||}{\textbf{a}} & 
\multicolumn{4}{ c||}{\textbf{b}} & 
\multicolumn{4}{ c||}{\textbf{c}} & 
\multicolumn{4}{ c| }{\textbf{d}} \\
\hline
aaaaaa & bbbbbb & cccccc & dddddd & 
aaaaaa & bbbbbb & cccccc & dddddd & 
aaaaaa & bbbbbb & cccccc & dddddd & 
aaaaaa & bbbbbb & cccccc & dddddd \\ 
\hline\hline
0.495 & 0.509 & 0.581 & 0.500 & 0.445 & 0.545 & 0.449 & 0.679 & 
0.536 & 0.600 & 0.392 & 0.736 & 0.509 & 0.454 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 
\hline
0.645 & 0.633 & 0.616 & 0.500 & 0.462 & 0.861 & 0.650 & 0.519 & 
0.600 & 0.570 & 0.592 & 0.536 & 0.675 & 0.693 & 0.552 & 0.500\\ 
\hline
0.549 & 0.489 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.572 & 0.510 & 0.457 & 0.467 & 
0.578 & 0.447 & 0.496 & 0.316 & 0.535 & 0.510 & 0.433 & 0.426\\ 
\hline
0.515 & 0.520 & 0.469 & 0.500 & 0.532 & 0.497 & 0.538 & 0.745 & 
0.626 & 0.588 & 0.569 & 0.591 & 0.615 & 0.623 & 0.536 & 0.452\\ 
\hline
0.760 & 0.471 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.749 & 0.542 & 0.574 & 0.379 & 
0.673 & 0.563 & 0.544 & 0.483 & 0.613 & 0.425 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 
\hline
0.604 & 0.527 & 0.430 & 0.500 & 0.469 & 0.498 & 0.547 & 0.400 & 
0.537 & 0.434 & 0.522 & 0.397 & 0.518 & 0.436 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 
\hline
0.524 & 0.479 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.715 & 0.528 & 0.658 & 0.585 & 
0.697 & 0.523 & 0.604 & 0.681 & 0.522 & 0.559 & 0.507 & 0.486\\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Version with lots of vertical and horizontal lines}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c *{14}{C} c @{}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}c}{\textbf{a}} & 
\multicolumn{4}{   c}{\textbf{b}} & 
\multicolumn{4}{   c}{\textbf{c}} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{\textbf{d}} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-4}   \cmidrule(lr){5-8}
\cmidrule(lr){9-12} \cmidrule(l){13-16}
aaaaaa & bbbbbb & cccccc & dddddd & 
aaaaaa & bbbbbb & cccccc & dddddd & 
aaaaaa & bbbbbb & cccccc & dddddd & 
aaaaaa & bbbbbb & cccccc & dddddd \\ 
\midrule
0.495 & 0.509 & 0.581 & 0.500 & 0.445 & 0.545 & 0.449 & 0.679 & 
0.536 & 0.600 & 0.392 & 0.736 & 0.509 & 0.454 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 
0.645 & 0.633 & 0.616 & 0.500 & 0.462 & 0.861 & 0.650 & 0.519 & 
0.600 & 0.570 & 0.592 & 0.536 & 0.675 & 0.693 & 0.552 & 0.500\\ 
0.549 & 0.489 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.572 & 0.510 & 0.457 & 0.467 & 
0.578 & 0.447 & 0.496 & 0.316 & 0.535 & 0.510 & 0.433 & 0.426\\ 
0.515 & 0.520 & 0.469 & 0.500 & 0.532 & 0.497 & 0.538 & 0.745 & 
0.626 & 0.588 & 0.569 & 0.591 & 0.615 & 0.623 & 0.536 & 0.452\\
0.760 & 0.471 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.749 & 0.542 & 0.574 & 0.379 & 
0.673 & 0.563 & 0.544 & 0.483 & 0.613 & 0.425 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 
0.604 & 0.527 & 0.430 & 0.500 & 0.469 & 0.498 & 0.547 & 0.400 & 
0.537 & 0.434 & 0.522 & 0.397 & 0.518 & 0.436 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 
0.524 & 0.479 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.715 & 0.528 & 0.658 & 0.585 & 
0.697 & 0.523 & 0.604 & 0.681 & 0.522 & 0.559 & 0.507 & 0.486\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Version with no vertical rules and with fewer but well-spaced horizontal rules}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank's. You are right, the second option is far more readable.

Answer (score 6):

see if the following table is acceptable to you:

[image]

that i can fit it onto text width, i reduce column hearer font to `\tiny` (in with this make it almost unreadable). so see, if you can broke them in two lines and with this make more narrow.

also i suggest to omit vertical lines and for horizontal use ruels from `\booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{\tiny #1}}    

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{16}{C}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{a}}  &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{b}}  &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{c}}  &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{d}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){ 1-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){ 5-8}
    \cmidrule(lr){ 9-12}
    \cmidrule(lr){13-16}
\mcx{aaaaaaa} & \mcx{bbbbbbb} & \mcx{ccccccc} & \mcx{ddddddd} &
\mcx{aaaaaaa} & \mcx{bbbbbbb} & \mcx{ccccccc} & \mcx{ddddddd} &
\mcx{aaaaaaa} & \mcx{bbbbbbb} & \mcx{ccccccc} & \mcx{ddddddd} &
\mcx{aaaaaaa} & \mcx{bbbbbbb} & \mcx{ccccccc} & \mcx{ddddddd}       \\
    \midrule
0.495 & 0.509 & 0.581 & 0.500 & 0.445 & 0.545 & 0.449 & 0.679 &
0.536 & 0.600 & 0.392 & 0.736 & 0.509 & 0.454 & 0.500 & 0.500       \\

0.645 & 0.633 & 0.616 & 0.500 & 0.462 & 0.861 & 0.650 & 0.519 &
0.600 & 0.570 & 0.592 & 0.536 & 0.675 & 0.693 & 0.552 & 0.500       \\
    \addlinespace
0.549 & 0.489 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.572 & 0.510 & 0.457 & 0.467 &
0.578 & 0.447 & 0.496 & 0.316 & 0.535 & 0.510 & 0.433 & 0.426       \\

0.515 & 0.520 & 0.469 & 0.500 & 0.532 & 0.497 & 0.538 & 0.745 &
0.626 & 0.588 & 0.569 & 0.591 & 0.615 & 0.623 & 0.536 & 0.452       \\
    \addlinespace
0.760 & 0.471 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.749 & 0.542 & 0.574 & 0.379 &
0.673 & 0.563 & 0.544 & 0.483 & 0.613 & 0.425 & 0.500 & 0.500       \\

0.604 & 0.527 & 0.430 & 0.500 & 0.469 & 0.498 & 0.547 & 0.400 &
0.537 & 0.434 & 0.522 & 0.397 & 0.518 & 0.436 & 0.500 & 0.500       \\
    \addlinespace
0.524 & 0.479 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.715 & 0.528 & 0.658 & 0.585 &
0.697 & 0.523 & 0.604 & 0.681 & 0.522 & 0.559 & 0.507 & 0.486       \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Caption}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
example, when you can set column headers in two lines:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx} % <--- added makecell
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\theadgape}{}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mcx[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{\thead{#1}}}
\usepackage{siunitx}                     % <--- added

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{16}{S[table-format=1.3]}}
    \toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{a}}  &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{b}}  &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{c}}  &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{d}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){ 1-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){ 5-8}
    \cmidrule(lr){ 9-12}
    \cmidrule(lr){13-16}
\mcx{aaaa\\ aaa}    & \mcx{bbbb\\ bbb}  & \mcx{cccc\\ ccc}  & \mcx{dddd\\ ddd}  &
\mcx{aaaa\\ aaa}    & \mcx{bbbb\\ bbb}  & \mcx{cccc\\ ccc}  & \mcx{dddd\\ ddd}  &
\mcx{aaaa\\ aaa}    & \mcx{bbbb\\ bbb}  & \mcx{cccc\\ ccc}  & \mcx{dddd\\ ddd}  &
\mcx{aaaa\\ aaa}    & \mcx{bbbb\\ bbb}  & \mcx{cccc\\ ccc}  & \mcx{dddd\\ ddd}  \\
     \midrule
0.495 & 0.509 & 0.581 & 0.500 & 0.445 & 0.545 & 0.449 & 0.679 &
0.536 & 0.600 & 0.392 & 0.736 & 0.509 & 0.454 & 0.500 & 0.500       \\
...
```

gives:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Having a `tabularx` without `X` columns doesn't actually make sense at all. The way a `tabularx` adjusts its width is to make the width of the X-columns to fit the available space. With no `X` columns `tabularx` can't do any adjustments for the width.

Another thing that doesn't really make sense, is that you're trying to scale the table to 80% of the text width with `\resizebox`, at the same time as you're using that `\makebox`.

What you could do is to replace `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}` with `\begin{tabular}`, remove the `\makebox`, and change the `\resizebox` width to `\textwidth`. If you in addition reduce the column spacing a bit by setting the `\tabcolsep` length, you get this output (for A4 paper with 2cm margins):

[image: output of code]

So this works, though I can't say I think it looks good. Less rules would be better. And using `\resizebox` should really be the very last resort for making a table fit. You could consider rotating it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % reduce space between columns
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{   %resize table

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c||}{\textbf{a}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c||}{\textbf{b}} 
& 
\multicolumn{4}{|c||}{\textbf{c}} & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{
\textbf{d}} \\
\hline
aaaaaaa & bbbbbbb & ccccccc & ddddddd & aaaaaaa & bbbbbbb & ccccccc & ddddddd & aaaaaaa & bbbbbbb & ccccccc & ddddddd & aaaaaaa & bbbbbbb & ccccccc & ddddddd\\ 
\hline\hline
0.495 & 0.509 & 0.581 & 0.500 & 0.445 & 0.545 & 0.449 & 0.679 & 0.536 & 0.
600 & 0.392 & 0.736 & 0.509 & 0.454 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 
\hline
0.645 & 0.633 & 0.616 & 0.500 & 0.462 & 0.861 & 0.650 & 0.519 & 0.600 & 0.
570 & 0.592 & 0.536 & 0.675 & 0.693 & 0.552 & 0.500\\ 
\hline
0.549 & 0.489 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.572 & 0.510 & 0.457 & 0.467 & 0.578 & 0.447 
& 0.496 & 0.316 & 0.535 & 0.510 & 0.433 & 0.426\\ 
\hline
0.515 & 0.520 & 0.469 & 0.500 & 0.532 & 0.497 & 0.538 & 0.745 & 0.626 & 0.588
& 0.569 & 0.591 & 0.615 & 0.623 & 0.536 & 0.452\\ 
\hline
0.760 & 0.471 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.749 & 0.542 & 0.574 & 0.379 & 0.673 & 0.563 
& 0.544 & 0.483 & 0.613 & 0.425 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 
\hline
0.604 & 0.527 & 0.430 & 0.500 & 0.469 & 0.498 & 0.547 & 0.400 & 0.537 & 0.434
& 0.522 & 0.397 & 0.518 & 0.436 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 
\hline
0.524 & 0.479 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.715 & 0.528 & 0.658 & 0.585 & 0.697 & 0.523 
& 0.604 & 0.681 & 0.522 & 0.559 & 0.507 & 0.486\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
}   %resize table

\caption{Caption}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

## Rotate

Here is one possible way of rotating the table. You haven't given any information about your layout, the `twocolumn` guess is only based on your use of `table*`, so could well be wrong.

[image: output of cod]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=2cm}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\begin{table}
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % reduce space between columns
\rotatebox{90}{%
\begin{minipage}{\textheight}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{16}{S[table-format=1.3]}} 
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{a}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{b}} 
& 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{c}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{
\textbf{d}} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-12} \cmidrule(l){13-16}
 {{aaaaaaa}} & {{bbbbbbb}} & {ccccccc} & {ddddddd} & {aaaaaaa} & {bbbbbbb} & {ccccccc} & {ddddddd} & {aaaaaaa} & {bbbbbbb} & {ccccccc} & {ddddddd} & {aaaaaaa} & {bbbbbbb} & {ccccccc} & {ddddddd}\\ \midrule

0.495 & 0.509 & 0.581 & 0.500 & 0.445 & 0.545 & 0.449 & 0.679 & 0.536 & 0.
600 & 0.392 & 0.736 & 0.509 & 0.454 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 

0.645 & 0.633 & 0.616 & 0.500 & 0.462 & 0.861 & 0.650 & 0.519 & 0.600 & 0.
570 & 0.592 & 0.536 & 0.675 & 0.693 & 0.552 & 0.500\\ 

0.549 & 0.489 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.572 & 0.510 & 0.457 & 0.467 & 0.578 & 0.447 
& 0.496 & 0.316 & 0.535 & 0.510 & 0.433 & 0.426\\ 

0.515 & 0.520 & 0.469 & 0.500 & 0.532 & 0.497 & 0.538 & 0.745 & 0.626 & 0.588
& 0.569 & 0.591 & 0.615 & 0.623 & 0.536 & 0.452\\ 

0.760 & 0.471 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.749 & 0.542 & 0.574 & 0.379 & 0.673 & 0.563 
& 0.544 & 0.483 & 0.613 & 0.425 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 

0.604 & 0.527 & 0.430 & 0.500 & 0.469 & 0.498 & 0.547 & 0.400 & 0.537 & 0.434
& 0.522 & 0.397 & 0.518 & 0.436 & 0.500 & 0.500\\ 

0.524 & 0.479 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.715 & 0.528 & 0.658 & 0.585 & 0.697 & 0.523 
& 0.604 & 0.681 & 0.522 & 0.559 & 0.507 & 0.486\\ 
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the documentclass you use (margins), the amount of data you want to show in the table (I assumed that there are not more than 7 rows of numbers) and the lengths of 'a' and 'aaaaaaa' maybe transposing (changing rows and columns) of the table could be an idea to fit the table into the textwidth. The below MWE shows such an approach with the additional use of `booktabs` for horizontal rules, and the `siunitx` package to align numbers in table cells with respect to the decimal separator. The vertical lines in the output image indicate the textwidth and are set by the package `showframe`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ll*7S[table-format=1.3]}
    \toprule
    \multirow{4}[0]{*}{a} & aaaaaaa   & 0.495 & 0.645 & 0.549 & 0.515 & 0.760 & 0.604 & 0.524 \\
          & bbbbbbb  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ccccccc   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ddddddd   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}[0]{*}{b} & aaaaaaa   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & bbbbbbb   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ccccccc   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ddddddd   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}[0]{*}{c} & aaaaaaa   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & bbbbbbb   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ccccccc   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ddddddd   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}[0]{*}{d} & aaaaaaa   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & bbbbbbb   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ccccccc   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ddddddd   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%

\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ll*7S[table-format=1.3]}
    \toprule
    \multirow{4}[0]{*}{a} & aaaaaaa   & 0.495 & 0.645 & 0.549 & 0.515 & 0.760 & 0.604 & 0.524 \\
          & bbbbbbb  &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ccccccc   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ddddddd   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}[0]{*}{b} & aaaaaaa   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & bbbbbbb   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ccccccc   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ddddddd   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}[0]{*}{c} & aaaaaaa   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & bbbbbbb   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ccccccc   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ddddddd   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{4}[0]{*}{d} & aaaaaaa   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & bbbbbbb   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ccccccc   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & ddddddd   &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest still  two other layout, which allows for normal size font. They use `hhline` and a plain `tabular`. The second has some colour for the table heads:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array, hhline}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\setlength{\doublerulesep}{4pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c|}
\hhline{----||----}
\multicolumn{4}{|c||}{\textbf{a}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{b}} \\
\hhline{----||----}
aaaaaaa & bbbbbbb & ccccccc & ddddddd & aaaaaaa & bbbbbbb & ccccccc & ddddddd\\
\hhline{====::====}
0.495 & 0.509 & 0.581 & 0.500 & 0.445 & 0.545 & 0.449 & 0.679\\
\hhline{----||----}
0.645 & 0.633 & 0.616 & 0.500 & 0.462 & 0.861 & 0.650 & 0.519 \\
\hhline{----||----}
0.549 & 0.489 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.572 & 0.510 & 0.457 & 0.467 \\
\hhline{----||----}
0.515 & 0.520 & 0.469 & 0.500 & 0.532 & 0.497 & 0.538 & 0.745\\
\hhline{----||----}
0.760 & 0.471 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.749 & 0.542 & 0.574 & 0.379 \\
\hhline{----||----}
0.604 & 0.527 & 0.430 & 0.500 & 0.469 & 0.498 & 0.547 & 0.400 \\
\hhline{----||----}
0.524 & 0.479 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.715 & 0.528 & 0.658 & 0.585 \\
\hhline{----||----}
\noalign{\vspace{3ex}}
\hhline{----||----}
\multicolumn{4}{|c||}{\textbf{c}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{d}}\\
\hhline{----||----}
 aaaaaaa & bbbbbbb & ccccccc & ddddddd & aaaaaaa & bbbbbbb & ccccccc & ddddddd \\
\hhline{====::====}
0.536 & 0.600 & 0.392 & 0.736 & 0.509 & 0.454 & 0.500 & 0.500 \\
\hhline{----||----}
0.600 & 0.570 & 0.592 & 0.536 & 0.675 & 0.693 & 0.552 & 0.500 \\
\hhline{----||----}
 0.578 & 0.447 & 0.496 & 0.316 & 0.535 & 0.510 & 0.433 & 0.426 \\
\hhline{----||----}
 0.626 & 0.588 & 0.569 & 0.591 & 0.615 & 0.623 & 0.536 & 0.452 \\
\hhline{----||----}
 0.673 & 0.563 & 0.544 & 0.483 & 0.613 & 0.425 & 0.500 & 0.500 \\
\hhline{----||----}
 0.537 & 0.434 & 0.522 & 0.397 & 0.518 & 0.436 & 0.500 & 0.500 \\
\hhline{----||----}
  0.697 & 0.523 & 0.604 & 0.681 & 0.522 & 0.559 & 0.507 & 0.486 \\
\hhline{----||----}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{array, booktabs, hhline}
    \usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table*}
    \centering
    \setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c||c|c|c|c|}
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{a}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{b}} \\
    \arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro!70! Lavender}
    \rowcolor{Gainsboro!70! Lavender} \multicolumn{1}{c}{aaaaaaa} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{bbbbbbb} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ccccccc} & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\hspace{2.4pt}}}{ddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace{-0.4pt}}c}{aaaaaaa} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{bbbbbbb} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ccccccc} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ddddddd}\\
\addlinespace[0.5ex]
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{black}}----||----}
    0.495 & 0.509 & 0.581 & 0.500 & 0.445 & 0.545 & 0.449 & 0.679\\
    \hhline{----||----}
    0.645 & 0.633 & 0.616 & 0.500 & 0.462 & 0.861 & 0.650 & 0.519 \\
    \hhline{----||----}
    0.549 & 0.489 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.572 & 0.510 & 0.457 & 0.467 \\
    \hhline{----||----}
    0.515 & 0.520 & 0.469 & 0.500 & 0.532 & 0.497 & 0.538 & 0.745\\
    \hhline{----||----}
    0.760 & 0.471 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.749 & 0.542 & 0.574 & 0.379 \\
    \hhline{----||----}
    0.604 & 0.527 & 0.430 & 0.500 & 0.469 & 0.498 & 0.547 & 0.400 \\
    \hhline{----||----}
    0.524 & 0.479 & 0.500 & 0.500 & 0.715 & 0.528 & 0.658 & 0.585 \\
    \hhline{----||----}
    \noalign{\vspace{3ex}}
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{c}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{d}}\\
    \arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro!70! Lavender}
    \hhline{----||----}
\rowcolor{Gainsboro!70! Lavender} \multicolumn{1}{c}{aaaaaaa} & \multicolumn{1} {c}{bbbbbbb} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ccccccc} & \multicolumn{1}{c!{\hspace{2.4pt}}}{ddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\hspace{-0.4pt}}c}{aaaaaaa} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{bbbbbbb} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ccccccc} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ddddddd} \\
\arrayrulecolor{black}
    \hhline{----::----}
    0.536 & 0.600 & 0.392 & 0.736 & 0.509 & 0.454 & 0.500 & 0.500 \\
    \hhline{----||----}
    0.600 & 0.570 & 0.592 & 0.536 & 0.675 & 0.693 & 0.552 & 0.500 \\
    \hhline{----||----}
     0.578 & 0.447 & 0.496 & 0.316 & 0.535 & 0.510 & 0.433 & 0.426 \\
    \hhline{----||----}
     0.626 & 0.588 & 0.569 & 0.591 & 0.615 & 0.623 & 0.536 & 0.452 \\
    \hhline{----||----}
     0.673 & 0.563 & 0.544 & 0.483 & 0.613 & 0.425 & 0.500 & 0.500 \\
    \hhline{----||----}
     0.537 & 0.434 & 0.522 & 0.397 & 0.518 & 0.436 & 0.500 & 0.500 \\
    \hhline{----||----}
      0.697 & 0.523 & 0.604 & 0.681 & 0.522 & 0.559 & 0.507 & 0.486 \\
    \hhline{----||----}
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \end{table*}

    \end{document}
```

[image]